# How to show and update total price with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to add a product and at the same time update the totalprice in the shopping cart.

```
$(".articel input[type='button']").click(function() {                   
    var price = $(this).siblings("input[name='price']").attr("value");
    var quantity = $(this).siblings("input[type='number']").attr("value");

    if (quantity % 1 != 0) {
        alert("You must add a whole number");
    }
    else if (quantity <= 0) {
        alert("You can not add a negative number or nothing");
    }
    else {
        var name = $(this).siblings("input[name='prodname']").attr("value");
        var ul = document.getElementById("buylist"); 
        var totalprice = quantity * price;
        var prod = name + " x " + quantity + "= " + totalprice + "$";
        var el = document.createElement("li"); 
        el.innerHTML = prod; 
        ul.appendChild(el); 
    }
});
});
```

Here is where the products and totalprice adds:

```
<h4>Shopping Cart</h4>
<div id="buylist">
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <div id="totalprice">
        <h4>Total price:<h4>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#checkout" onClick="checkOut()" class="click" data-toggle="tab" id="form">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

And here one of the forms where I add products to the cart

```
<form class="articel">
    Quantity: <input type="number" style="width:30px;"><br>
    Add to cart: <input type="button" class="btn">
    <input type="hidden" value="30" name="price">
    <input type="hidden" value="The walking dead" name="prodname">
</form>
```

Comment: so it adds a product and the total price of the number of that product. The problem is when I want to add one more product the total price of all products in cart should appear at the bottom of the products in the cart. Is there any simple way of doing this? (or not simple...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't really understand. But when the products or their quantity change, you have to calculate the price. I suggest, that you already have an event for both of those actions. Then I'd run a function who calculates the price.

Now it depends if you already have a fix price or also have to multiply that with the quantity. Loop through the products and calculate the price.

NOTE: To select the price & quantity I used selectors which you actually don't have in your code.

```
function calculatePrice() {
    var quantity, price, sum = 0;
    //loop through product "blocks"
    $('.articel').each(function() {
        price = $(this).children('.price').val();
        quantity = $(this).children('.quantity').val();
        //Add price to sum if number
        if (!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(quantity)) {
            sum += price * quantity;
        }
    });
    //Update Price
    $('#totalprice').html('<h4>Total price:' + sum + '</h4');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the price and quantity to the UL you can process easily:

```
<ul>
  <li data-quantity="X" data-price="Z">...</li>
</ul>
```

Add this function to the javascript file.

```
function calcTotal (ul) {
  var newTotal = 0;
  ul.find('li').each( function(i,e) {
    var li = $(e);
    newTotal += li.data('quantity') * li.data('price');
  });
}
```

Then in your code, where there is the last else:

```
itemPrice = quantity * price;
var prodDesc = name + " x " + quantity + "= " + itemPrice + "$";//same as it was.
var newLi = $("<li>");
newLi.text(prodDesc).data('quantity', quantity).data('price', price);
ul.append(newLi);
var totalPrice = calcTotal(ul);
$('#totalprice h4').text('Total Price: ' + totalPrice);
```

More or less that's it.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to add the newTotal and then just update it everytime you add something new.

Comment: I believe you would put pdjota's script in its own function, then call it in the 'add to cart' script